# Determining asymptotic distribution of a sequence

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I'm completely stumped on this concept, especially wrapping my head around series. For instance, I'm stuck on this question and don't really know how to proceed.

For $X_1,...,X_n,...$ which are independent identically distributed $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variables (non-zero $\mu$), and $T_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, determine the limiting distribution of

$$(\sqrt{n}(T_n^2 - \mu^2))_{n\geq1}$$

I've tried a couple of things but have no idea if they're legal operations. First I constructed $Y_n = \sum_{i=0}^nX_i \in N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$, so that $T_n = \frac{1}{n}Y_n$. Also it's true that

$$(\sqrt{n}(T_n^2 - \mu^2))_{n\geq1} = (\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}Y_n + \mu)(\frac{1}{n}Y_n-\mu))_{n\geq1}$$

The distributions of the quadratic terms are $N(n\mu\pm\mu,n\sigma^2)$, right? Is it possible to "multiply" their respective cumulative distribution functions together to form a compound one, which is normalized by $\sqrt{n}$?

Any and all advice and pointers/help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a "delta method" problem.

Comment: But how can I verify that $\sqrt{n}(T_n - \mu)$ converges in distribution to $N(0, \sigma^2)$, as is required?

Comment: Either by using the central limit theorem, or by remembering how the sum of independent gaussian rvs are distributed.